# Non-mathematical formalizations of physics?

Tags: universe, nature

The deeper I carve into physics, the more clear it becomes to me that there might be a better way to analyze the universe than our mathematical frameworks. Not like defining new algebras or thinking outside the box - I feel there must be something bigger than math itself that we can use to make predictions. What this is though, I have no idea. This has always been a bit of a shower thought in the back of my mind for the last few months in my physics education. I wanted to ask if this possibility has been considered seriously before or ideas physicists have had about non-mathematical formalizations.

**Edit: (I'm not talking about spiritual chakra stuff, try and take the question seriously please)**

Perhaps a better phrasing would be that for the strong predictive power that math has shown us, we have always taken the approach that we should just keep making better theories or increase our measurement precision with different mathematical methods. But there may be ways to tackle theoretical problems that utilize a non-mathematical framework we haven't thought of. If math is like a skill tree of branching possibilities to tackle problems, maybe the non-perfection of physical theories can't be solved by going further down the math skill tree, but by finding a new skill tree all together (not philosophy). It's a silly analogy, but I don't think it's a stupid possibility to consider.

Comment: "I feel there must be something bigger (...)". What makes you feel this way? In my view the co-development of maths and physics over the last 200-300 years has taken human civilizations forward like no other academic disciplines. The accuracy of predictions done with e.g. quantum electrodynamics are *astonishing*, there is no other way to put it.

Comment: Besides math, what alternative tool would make predictions?  Tarot cards?

Comment: Spiritual questions or questions about *philosophy of science* are better asked at philosophy SE - this community is really about the mainstream physics

Comment: Required reading: [*"The unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics in the natural sciences."*](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/wigner.pdf) [pdf link] by Wigner

Comment: Closed. As I said, those who don't want to face the issue hate the question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Wigner cherry-picks his math and cherry-picks his phenomena. Math is often profoundly ineffective. Consider that a molecule can find its ground state in picoseconds without calculating anything, while it takes a massive supercomputer calculation to find it with math.

Comment: Are you aware of Stephen’s Wolfram’s [ideas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_New_Kind_of_Science) about algorithms and discrete computation replacing math as the foundation of physics?

Comment: You are asking to forget the revolution that Newton brought to what was philosophy for 2000 years, when theories were non mathematical philosophies  ( Democritus) with a bit of algebra at best (Pythagoras) , and after 1500 years at best in fitting observations  (Galileo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an excellent question, but, of course, some who don't want to face the issue hate it.

Mathematics is an essential tool of physics. We've been using it for millennia, and we've never found an adequate substitute. Physics is not founded on mathematics: the phenomena of the real world are in charge. However, to probe those phenomena, we need experiments. Experiments employ a variety of tools, and mathematics may be the most important. You need math to design experiments, reduce the results, and capture observed patterns in theory.

The objects of mathematics don't exist in the real world. There are no points, lines, circles, or even numbers, really. These things are all abstractions, products of human imagination. Mathematics finds the necessary properties of these abstractions. And then, it turns out that carefully selected mathematical abstractions prove to be useful and even extendable representations of real phenomena.

The connection isn't perfect, and the imperfections are troublesome. Even when the process goes well, tension between the phenomena and the math leads to various controversies of "interpretation". It would be nice to have a better tool, but haven't found it: all we've found is better math.

But we can't even agree with mathematicians on what "better math" is. Mathematician Jack Schwartz, in his excellent essay "The Pernicious influence of Mathematics on Science" comments on "the sorry history of the Dirac Delta function".

Answer (score 11):

I think this is misunderstanding of what science is: unlike philosophy, its goal is not understanding the Universe for the sake of understanding, but *understanding in order to make quantitative predictions*, thus permitting improving human condition (e.g., with the aid of new machines.) *Quantitative* by definition implies math.

Comment: +1. The individual goals of theorists can also be to find philosophy or beauty in the math. Predictions are most important though. Einstein was heavily inspired by philosophical ideas of relativity.

Comment: *"unlike philosophy, its goal is not understanding the Universe for the sake of understanding, but understanding in order to make quantitative predictions"*. I disagree. The core of science is understanding and knowing for the sake of it; quantitative results imply a *deeper* form of understanding, if anything. I'm not saying science is not about making prediction, I'm saying that this does not exclude we want to be able to make such predictions just for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: While I can't argue with the necessity of quantitative predictions, I would dispute the claim that the only possible way to ever make quantitative predictions is through the mathematical framework we have invented. Do you really think there will *never* be another way to formalize physics discovered in the multi-trillion year future of the universe other than human math?

Comment: @Dutonic *quantitative* is mathematics. There are different mathematical frameworks and there may be new ones, but it remains math. You would need to provide specific definition of mathematics, to show what falls outside of it. Still, I recommend asking your question in philosophy SE. Here it is likely to he perceived as trolling.

Comment: +1, but the goal of understanding the universe for the sake of understanding drives physics too. We are very unlikely to make new machines that use the Higgs field, but we want to understand it. What makes it physics is that it is verifiable. What makes it philosophy is that it isn't. Math is a big part of repeatable experiments that make physics verifiable.

Answer (score 3):

Physics is a description of the behavior of the universe. We find repetitive patterns of behavior that can be described by math.

Math models ideas. E.G. loosely, a vector space captures the idea of things that can be added together. A normed vector space captures things that have a size that can be added together. These kinds of ideas reflect the patterns of behavior.

Math also makes measurements possible. Without this, physics would have no precise descriptions.

If you find a replacement for math, it would need these two functions. It seems it might look an awful lot like math.

On the other hand, there is more than one way to describe the universe. Quantum mechanics started with a matrix description and a wave description. It took a while to show they were the same. The way physicists think about it conceivably could be replaced by something different. Conceptual breakthroughs have happened in the past. The ancient Greeks thought of numbers as integers or ratios of integers. They were stumped by $\sqrt{2}$.

We find that vectors work well for linear problems. We might need some bigger idea to make non-linearity more tractable. I would speculate that some bigger form of math would be helpful. But how would I rule out something that isn't math? Given a total lack of ideas, it is hard to say anything useful.

Finally, it should be said we do have an alternative non-mathematical description of physics. It is our intuitive understanding of the concepts. Vectors are like little arrows. Electrons are like point particles. Energy is like a substance that can be transformed but never created or destroyed.

We don't pay nearly as much attention to this as we do to the mathematics. But we do use it to informally guide our thinking. It helps in ways the math does not. We aren't as concerned with how accurate this picture is as we are with the mathematics. We switch pictures as convenient. Electrons are sometimes like waves.